# Guava way of sorting List according to another list?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have `List<Integer>` consisting Ids of my Users. And after a database query, I am retrieving `List<User>`. I would like to order this list according to first Id list. `List<User>` may not include some of the Ids. What is the Guava way for sorting this list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fully "functional" way, using Guava, would combine `Ordering#explicit()` with `Ordering#onResultOf()`

```
public class UserService {

    @Inject private UserDao userDao;

    public List<User> getUsersWithIds(List<Integer> userIds) {
        List<User> users = userDao.loadUsersWithIds(userIds);
        Ordering<User> orderById = Ordering.explicit(userIds).onResultOf(UserFunctions.getId());
        return orderById.immutableSortedCopy(users);
    }

}
```

You could declare an anonymous function inline, but I like to declare my functions as static factory methods in a separate class, for a cleaner code (the verbosity of Java's function declarations is hidden in the utility class):

```
/**
 * Static factory methods to create {@link Function}s for {@link User}s.
 */
public final class UserFunctions {
    private UserFunctions() { /* prevents instantiation */ }

    /**
     * @return a {@link Function} that returns an {@link User}'s id.
     */
    public static Function<User, Integer> getId() {
        return GetIdFunction.INSTANCE;
    }

    // enum singleton pattern
    private enum GetIdFunction implements Function<User, Integer> {
        INSTANCE;

        public Integer apply(User user) {
            return user.getId();
        }
    }

}
```

---

As mentioned by @Arne in a comment, this can be simplified in Java 8, using a method reference instead of the `UserFunctions` class:

```
public class UserService {

    @Inject private UserDao userDao;

    public List<User> getUsersWithIds(List<Integer> userIds) {
        List<User> users = userDao.loadUsersWithIds(userIds);
        Ordering<User> orderById = Ordering.explicit(userIds).onResultOf(User::getId);
        return orderById.immutableSortedCopy(immutableSortedCopy(users));
    }

}
```

Comment: With java 8 you can get rid of the whole function and use a method reference instead. The line would then look like this (and no extra function): Ordering<User> orderById = Ordering.explicit(userIds).onResultOf(User::getId);

Answer (score 11):

I don't think Guava has anything specific to do this. But it's just a matter of writing this comparator:

```
Collections.sort(userList, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
         int i1 = idList.indexOf(u1.getId());
         int i2 = idList.indexOf(u2.getId());
         return Ints.compare(i1, i2);
    }
}
```

Now that I think about it, it can also be implemented this way:

```
final Ordering<Integer> idOrdering = Ordering.explicit(idList);
Collections.sort(userList, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
         return idOrdering.compare(u1.getId(), u2.getId());
    }
}
```

which is probably more efficient.

Comment: This not efficient because of the linear time requirement of indexOf method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Others have already answered your question using Guava. Here is a [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) answer.

Please note that you'll have to use immutable data structures from the library in order to avail of all the goodness.

```
F<User, Integer> indexInIdList = new F<User, Integer>() {
  public Integer f(User u) {
    return idList.elementIndex(Equal.intEqual, u.getId()).toNull();
  }
};
userList.sort(Ord.intOrd.comap(indexInIdList));
```

Comment: Thanks :) Love this library too. :)

Comment: An aside: In Scala, the solution would be just `userList.sortBy(idList.indexOf(_.id))`.

Comment: We will get something similar with java 8 ;)

Comment: @Premraj, lambda expressions alone are insufficient to pull off all the Scala collections magic. ;) There is a lot of stuff at work here: [fundeps](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies), higher kinds, type-classes, mixin composition etc.

Comment: @missingfaktor - Agreed and there are reasons not to include some of the mentioned features in java.. anyways at least java will get some basic functional behavior with Java8 and that's a good start :)

Comment: @Premraj, yeah, agree with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer using Google Guava

```
class Form {
  public Integer index; // for simplicity, no setter/getter included
}

List<Form> forms = ... // list instances, each of each with values for index

// ordering of forms by the ui sort index.
private static final Ordering<Form> sorter = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(new Function<Form, Integer>() {

    @Override
    public Integer apply(Form form) {
       return form.index;
    }
});

private List<Form> sortForms(List<Form> forms) {
    return sorter.sortedCopy(forms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this with Java 8 lambdas.

```
List<Integer> ids = ...; List<User> users = ...;
//map ids to their list indices, to avoid repeated indexOf calls
Map<Integer, Integer> rankMap = IntStream.range(0, ids.size()).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(ids::get, Function.identity()));
//sort on the id's position in the list
users.sort(Comparator.comparing(u -> rankMap.get(u.id())));
```

Comment: I think you need to make sure no nulls appear as id, as the OP said there could be nulls

Answer (score 0):

Hardly found a Kotlin answer so I'm posting this here.

`list2.sortedBy { Pair(it, list1.indexOf(it.typeOfList1)).second }`

And the full TU I wrote to find the answer :

```kotlin
enum class Categorie { UNO, DOS, TRES, QUATROS }
data class Song(val name: String, val categorie: Categorie)

fun main() {
    val categories = arrayListOf(Categorie.QUATROS, Categorie.DOS, Categorie.TRES, Categorie.UNO)
    val songs = arrayListOf(
        Song("s1", Categorie.DOS),
        Song("s2", Categorie.DOS),
        Song("s3", Categorie.UNO),
        Song("s4", Categorie.QUATROS),
        Song("s5", Categorie.TRES),
        Song("s6", Categorie.QUATROS)
    )

    val expectedSortedListOfSongs = arrayListOf(
        Song("s4", Categorie.QUATROS),
        Song("s6", Categorie.QUATROS),
        Song("s1", Categorie.DOS),
        Song("s2", Categorie.DOS),
        Song("s5", Categorie.TRES),
        Song("s3", Categorie.UNO)
    )

    val sortedList: List<Song> = songs.sortedBy { Pair(it, categories.indexOf(it.categorie)).second }

    println("isValid=${sortedList == expectedSortedListOfSongs}")
}
```